# Why am I getting np.NaN values when trying to add a column to a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with date information stored as a string. I want to extract the month from each date directly, so I tried this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['2015-04-16', 5], ['2014-05-01', 6]],columns = ['date','units'])
df['month'] = df['month'].str[5,7]
print(df)
```

This gives the following output

```
    date  units  month
0  2015-04-16      5    NaN
1  2014-05-01      6    NaN
```

The dtype for the NaN's is float, and I have no idea why. Why doesn't this just create another column with the substrings?

Comment: When I run your code, I just get a `KeyError`, because you don't have a column named `a`. You meant `df['date']` there, or something different?

Comment: Also, is the issue here that you don't know about Python/NumPy/Pandas slicing syntax, or just that you made a typo and used `,` where you meant `:`? I'm assuming it's the latter, and you don't need any explanation.

Comment: I replaced 'a' with 'date' as it should have been. You're right - I messed up the slicing by using a comma rather than a colon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that your slicing is invalid:

```
In [7]:

df = pd.DataFrame([['2015-04-16', 5], ['2014-05-01', 6]],columns = ['date','units'])
df['date'].str[5,7]
​
Out[7]:
0   NaN
1   NaN
Name: date, dtype: float64
```

Compare with this:

```
t='2015-04-16'
t[5,7]
```

this raises a:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

I think you wanted:

```
In [18]:

df = pd.DataFrame([['2015-04-16', 5], ['2014-05-01', 6]],columns = ['date','units'])
df['month'] = df['date'].str[5:7]
df
Out[18]:
         date  units month
0  2015-04-16      5    04
1  2014-05-01      6    05
```

So as this is an invalid operation pandas is returning `NaN`

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to slice each string to get the substring from 5 to 7, you need a `:`, not a `,`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['2015-04-16', 5], ['2014-05-01', 6]],columns = ['date','units'])
>>> df['month'] = df['date'].str[5:7]
>>> print(df)
         date  units month
0  2015-04-16      5    04
1  2014-05-01      6    05
```